# scraping data and collecting all href values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the following webpage: https://opensea.io/rankings?sortBy=total_volume

And I want to collect all the href values so for example:

[image: value to scrape]

However, it seems like I can't do it and I get some sort of error when using beautiful soup. This is the code that I have so far:

```
page = requests.get("https://opensea.io/rankings?sortBy=total_volume").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
values = soup.findAll('a')
```

I'm not too sure why, but I would like to get all the values that is shown in the href values which contain the word "/collection/"

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You are redirected to an error page here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you're getting the **403 Forbidden** error -  the site probably has some very good blockers, I made a quick attempt with ScrapingAnt and then tried copying the entire request for my browser, but both were blocked.

If you're open to trying selenium, I have [this function](https://gist.github.com/Driftr95/cbae6710c134df708f44ade8503f6638) for cases like this - you can paste it to your code and then just call it

```py
soup = linkToSoup_selenium('https://opensea.io/rankings?sortBy=total_volume')
values = soup.find_all(
            lambda l: l.name == 'a' and
            l.get('href') is not None and
            '/collection/' in l.get('href')
        )
# OR
# values = [a for a in soup.select('a') if a.get('href') and '/collection/' in a.get('href')]
```

---

---

**EDIT:**
To get ALL the collections:

```py
# from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import json

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = f'https://opensea.io/rankings?sortBy=total_volume'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
scrollCt = 0
rows = []

maxScrols = 1000  # adjust as preferred
while scrollCt < maxScrols:
    time.sleep(0.3)  # adjust as necessary - I seem to need  >0.25s
    aro = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        'a[role="row"][overflow="hidden"][href*="/collection/"]')
    aro = [(
        a.get_attribute('href'),
        a.find_element_by_xpath('../..')  # parent's parent
    ) for a in aro]

    aroFil = [a for a in aro if a[0] not in [h['link'] for h in rows]]
    aroFil = [{   
        'outerHTML': [a[1].get_attribute('outerHTML')], # for BeatifulSoup
        'innerText': a[1].get_attribute('innerText').strip(),
        'link': a[0]
    } for a in aroFil]
    rows += aroFil

    print(f'[{scrollCt}] found {len(aro)}, filtered down to {len(aroFil)} rows [at {len(rows)} total]')
    if aroFil == []:
        # break # if you don't want to go to next page
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@value="arrow_forward_ios"]/..').click()
        except Exception as e:
            print('failed to go to next page', str(e))
            break

    scrollCt += 1
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)


# if you want to extract more with BeautifulSoup
for i, r in enumerate(rows):
    rSoup = BeautifulSoup(r['outerHTML'][0].encode('utf-8'), 'html5lib')

    rows[i]['bs4Text'] = rSoup.get_text(strip=True)
    ###### EXTRACT INFO AS NEEDED ######

    del rows[i]['html']  # if you don't need it anymore

# with open('x.json', 'w') as f: json.dump(rows, f, indent=4) # save json file 

driver.quit()
```

Comment: oh well that worked like a charm ! but for some reason, it only gave the top 38 items as opposed to all of it. Do you know how i can get all of the 100 items ? 

I supposed it would be because we have to manually scroll down or something ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls wow. this is a *very* dynamic page apparently. I don't think my function will suffice for getting all 100 items; you'll probably have to write custom code - even scrolling to the bottom of the page isn't enough, because when you scroll down, *some of the top elements **get removed*** as newer element are added at the bottom...you might have to scroll down by your screen height and collect data after every scroll (and then filter down to uniques because there will probably be overlap)

Comment: really appreciate the help ! but yeah, this page is definitely one of the harder sites i have seen

Comment: @PutsandCalls you probably don't need it anymore, but I've added an edit with code for getting all the items [I decided I need to practice scrolling with selenium, but then gave up because I couldn't figure out how to find the coordinates of the bottom item  - frustratingly, it's *not* always (or ever, apparently) the last item - but a simple `body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)` seems to work well enough so...]

Comment: this actually worked really well, definitely helped a ton ! thanks a lot